# Reference to service from dynamically added component in Angular 6 CLI

Tags: javascript, angular

I created a directive in Angular 6 named '`DeleteDirective`' and reference to a service '`DeleteService`' to make sure I can delete an item from my application. After the item is marked as deleted (in PHP back-end), I'll show an Undo element via the '`UndoComponent`' that I dynamically added in the `DeleteService`. No problems so far.

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appDelete]'
})

export class DeleteDirective {
constructor(
        @Inject(ViewContainerRef) viewContainerRef,
        renderer: Renderer2
    ) {
        service.renderer = renderer;
        service.setRootViewContainerRef(viewContainerRef);
        service.addUndoElement();
    }

@HostListener('click') onClick() {
    // (Some code to execute deletion)
    this.deleteService.showUndoElement();

}
```

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DeleteService {
constructor(
        rendererFactory: RendererFactory2,
        private factoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
        private appRef: ApplicationRef,
    ) {
        this.renderer = rendererFactory.createRenderer(null, null);
        this.factoryResolver = factoryResolver;
    }

setRootViewContainerRef(viewContainerRef) {
    this.rootViewContainer = viewContainerRef;
}

addUndoElement() {
        const factory = this.factoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(UndoComponent);
        const component = factory.create(this.rootViewContainer);
        // this.rootViewContainer.insert(component.hostView);
        this.appRef.attachView(component.hostView);
        const domElem = (component.hostView as EmbeddedViewRef<any>)
            .rootNodes[0] as HTMLElement;
        document.body.appendChild(domElem);
    }
}
```

Now, in the UndoComponent HTML I created a link to undo the action, named `restoreItem`. I would like to use another service named `ListService` to get some data again.

```
@Injectable()
export class UndoComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private listService: ListService) {

    }

    restoreItem() {
        this.currentList = this.listService.getSelectedList();
        console.log(this.currentList); // null
    }
}
```

It seems I cannot reference to the `ListService` (or any other service) from this dynamically added component to the DOM. It returns `null`. Any ideas how I can access a service from a dynamically added Component? Thanks so much for any directions!

**Edit: added `Listservice` stub code for clarification**

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ListService {

    lists: List[];
    list: List[];
    currentList: List;

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

setSelectedList(list: List): void {
        this.currentList = list;
    }

    getSelectedList(): List {
        return this.currentList;
    }

    private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
        console.log(error);
        return throwError('Error! something went wrong.');
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you call `restoreItem`? Try defining it as an arrow function: `restoreItem = () => { ... }`.

Comment: Could you show **ListService** implementation please?

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting the value of currentList in ListService in anyway.

setSelectedList in ListService is never called which is being used to set value of currentList. So currentList remains null.